# React / D3 error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null"

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to bind some data to a dom element using `d3` but in the context of react.  I can't find any problems with the d3 code so I'm wondering if I'm handling the React lifecycle / ref's incorrectly.

```
import React from "react";
import { select, selectAll } from "d3-selection";

class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeD3();
  }

  makeD3 = () => {
    console.log("maked3");
    selectAll(this.refs.node).data([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    select(this.refs.node).data([1, 2, 3, 4]);  // try just select?
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="node">test</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you just have one DOM node, maybe `select(this.refs.node).data([1]);` will work?

Comment: but i haven't seen that from the d3 docs?  i thought you can just bind the data and then it will let you add nodes via `enter` and `update`